# How to display exception text in a custom error page on Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on Symfony and I created a custom error page, following the instruction of the Symfony documentation.

So, I have my app/Ressources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig file. It works fine, but in my error view, I want to display the Exception text, so that if I do this in a controller:

```
throw new \Exception('Ooops !');
```

...i can display the value 'Ooops !' in my Twig View.

Do someone knows which Twig variable have this information ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I finally found the answer : the Exception Message is simply accessible by the **exception.message** variable in the Twig error template.

Comment: A few years later, a little more info about this solution. Be really careful about where you use this, because it can contain useful informations for an attacker like database credentials, Symfony version or clues about the filesystem or the OS. I strongly discourage its usage to display every Exception messages in production (can be ok for Exception subclasses or in an internal usage).

Answer (score 1):

@Maxime

Indeed that's the way i do it as well.

I just want to mentioned that I encountered the problem when using exception.message that some of the generic errors are also rendered in your custom error page which will lead to exception messages like

**"No route found for GET /any_route_that_is_not_defined "**

which is the default when calling a page that really does not exists by definition

I didn't found a way to surpress or translate these messages yet :/

Comment: Yes, I realised that... It's quite embarassing, more for security reasons (SQL errors which give some informations to potential hackers) I think ! It's a pity... Maybe using a listener it's possible to distinct our exceptions and Symfony's ones

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the Symfony doc on [how to customize error pages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html).

You have the message in `{{ status_text }}` and the exception code in `{{ status_code }}`.

Comment: Thanks but the status_code and status_text variables just returns the general error information (like 404 Not Found). And I wanted the Exception detailed message.