# Symfony 4 : AccessDeniedHttpException() get access custom variables

Tags: symfony, twig

In my RequestListener.php, if an entity is not accessible for a user, i use the following exception :

```
throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
```

So it returns me my custom 403 error html template using twig.

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid exception">
    <table class="wrapper">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="error-code">
                    <span>403</span>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h1 class="text-light">Test h1</h1>
                        <h2 class="text-light">Test h2</h2>
                        <p>
                            Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now what I want to do is, for the same :

```
throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
```

Using different message depending on the situation where occurs the error 403.

For example what i tried to do is :

```
throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('custom');
```

In my template 403.html.twig

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid exception">
<table class="wrapper">
    <tr>
        <td>
            {% if status_text %}
               {{ status_text }}
            {% else %}
            <div class="error-code">
                <span>403</span>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h1 class="text-light">Test h1</h1>
                    <h2 class="text-light">Test h2</h2>
                    <p>
                        Test
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I don't know if the string passed in the exception is reachable in my error template...

Comment: You could always try to see what is in `status_text` using `{{ dump(status_text) }}`.

Comment: With APP_ENV=dev it shows me "custom" with the correct 403 exception (but not my html template, it's the debug page by default)

With APP_ENV=prod , dump not working and displaying the variable directly show nothing...

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19814235/5165724. You could be able to achieve what you want using the `exception.message` variable in twig.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Exactly what i wanted !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe have a look at this:
[How to display exception text in a custom error page on Symfony?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19814235/5165724).

You can use the `exception.message` variable in twig.

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid exception">
<table class="wrapper">
    <tr>
        <td>
            {% if exception.message %}
               {{ exception.message }}
            {% else %}
            <div class="error-code">
                <span>403</span>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h1 class="text-light">Test h1</h1>
                    <h2 class="text-light">Test h2</h2>
                    <p>
                        Test
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```